# Nuxtjs - What files /folders do you need to deploy production version on host

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

https://nuxtjs.org/guide/commands#development-environment

There is no mention of the files required by Nuxt when deploying it to live hosting.

Using Nuxt CLI, creates several empty folders such as

assets
components
layouts
pages
server

Using npm build .nuxt folder is created - do i simply upload the content of the full folder or are the dist folder….????

I have tried several combinations of uploading the full contents of .nuxt vs only parts. I havent had any luck.

Comment: universal mode?

Comment: correct- i am using universal mode

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need .nuxt folder, static folder, your nuxt.config.js and a node_modules directory for deployment in universal mode

For deploying on plesk you can see this example https://github.com/pi0/nuxt-plesk-example

Comment: Thanks!  if my website root is /public/ would i upload the files like /public/.nuxt/.. /public/static/.. /public/node_modules/... /public/static etc or would i treat the contents within the .nuxt folder as the root and upload it directly to /public/.. so i would have for example /public/server.js  and then have the folder structure maintained within .nuxt just on /public/whatever ??

Comment: @Jujubes your question kind of assumes that u want static files. But universal mode mean that you have to run node server on your server which will serve request, so it dont matter where to place...

Comment: I dont want static files. I am running node. I just have no clue what to upload and there doesnt seem to be a clear answer on the docs.

Comment: when i run npm builld the .nuxt folder is created and it contains a bunch of files and folders. i have no clue what to put onto my website root on the server(hosting)

Comment: @Jujubes, what hosting are you using?

Comment: linux centos 7 with plesk

Comment: Oh wow that is an eye opener which definately leads to more questions regarding babel/ webpack

Comment: Should I reconfigure babel/ webpack

Comment: @Jujubes what for ?

Comment: Mainly to eliminate any unsupported API functions such as import instead of require

Comment: Nuxt do all transpiring by default

Comment: Cool cool. So in assuming this is done at runtime. Isn't that kinda slow

Comment: To clarify, i basically upload my existing files as is to plesk(thats what you github page suggests). The build process using the prescribed scripts in package.json is not done. So i have uploaded uncompiled docs that will be converted once i tell plesk to start node which will spin up the site?

Comment: It all stated in that link. You either build it on start or you use run script to build it once

Comment: Read and now in running into a problem with babel-loader it indicates that .nuxt/client.js does not exist and after running the build script on plesk it's definitely there

Comment: @Aldarund i am getting the following error from your gitpage tutorial https://postimg.cc/w1vQqymS and the file does exist

Comment: @Jujubes you can go to nuxt discord where you should get better help than here in comments. Its hard to say what u are doing wrong, but if u follow tutorial it should work

Comment: @Aldarund instead of uploading the docs i pulled from a git and it works now - no clue why